# How do I properly specify the location of my proto files in protocol buffers?

Tags: protocol-buffers, protoc

Here are the three files I am working with:

```
// city.proto
syntax = "proto3";
package city;

message City {

    string cityName = 1;
    string zipCode = 2;
    string countryName = 3;

}
```

```
// street.proto
syntax = "proto3";

import "Exercise/city.proto";
package street;

message Street {

    string cityName = 1;
    city.City city = 2;

}
```

```
// building.proto
syntax = "proto3";

import "Exercise/street.proto";
package building;

message Building {

    string buildingName = 1;
    string buildingNumber = 2;
    street.Street street = 3;

}
```

This is my current directory structure:

```
   - PROTOCOLBUFFERS (folder on desktop)
        - Exercise
           - city.proto
           - street.proto
           - building.proto
```

This is the command I'm using to generate code from the proto files
`protoc -I="."/Exercise --java_out=Exercise Exercise/*.proto`

I am running this command with my terminal inside the PROTOCOLBUFFERS folder.

What am I doing wrong in the execution of this command? I am on windows.
This is the error message I get and online search for it hasn't been useful.

> building.proto:3:1: Import "Exercise/street.proto" was not found or had errors. 
> building.proto:10:5: "street.Street" is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfamiliar with running `protoc` on Windows, but...

Try each of these in turn:

1. Replacing the Linux path separator `/` with the Windows separator `\`.
2. Using absolute paths from the drive root: `protoc --proto_path=c:\...\Exercise --java_out=Exercise c:\...\Exercise\*.proto`, i.e. replace `c:\...` with the correct path.
3. If that doesn't work, replace the single wildcard (`*.proto`) with full qualified paths to each proto `c:\...\Exercise\city.proto c:\...\Exercise\building.proto c:\...\Exercise\street.proto`

`protoc` is "picky". If you need to use a `proto_path`, you should repeat the appropriate path in subsequent references to proto files.

I am surprised to see that the documentation suggests that "import" is not supported in Java!? I use languages other than Java and would be surprised if this were true, but it is what it says:

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#importing_definitions

Answer (score 0):

You should change your import path in the proto files: they are already in the same folder. So change as example:

```
// street.proto
syntax = "proto3";

import "city.proto";
```

instead of

```
// street.proto
syntax = "proto3";

import "Exercise/city.proto";
```

After this fix, the command generates the files as:

```
.
├── Exercise
│   ├── building
│   │   └── BuildingOuterClass.java
│   ├── building.proto
│   ├── city
│   │   └── CityOuterClass.java
│   ├── city.proto
│   ├── street
│   │   └── StreetOuterClass.java
│   └── street.proto
└── README.md
```

Hope this help